# char *p and getenv method signature

Tags: c, pointers

The method signature for getenv
`char *getenv(const char *name)`
The return value is a pointer to char .

Now if we look at the below example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() 
{
  
char *p;
p = getenv("PATH");
if(p != NULL)
 printf("Current path is %s", p);

return 0;


}
```

The only confusion here is the "p" printed with format specifier "%s" as String  but what about the **Pointer Dereference**
If I put "*p" instead, I end up with segmentation fault
while if I want to get the pointer address I can do this
`printf("%p", p);`
confusion about getting the value by deferencing  the point "p" in our case.
Please explain

Comment: `*p` is a single `char` but you must provide the address of a string for format specifier `%s`. How would `printf` ever be able to know where the other characters of your string can be found if you don't provide the address?

Comment: "%s" expects a `char*` or `const char*`. Any dereferencing needed is done in `printf`

Comment: You should already get a compiler warning about parameter type mismatch if you provide `*p`

Comment: BTW: That thing is called a "pointer", not a "point".

Comment: Gerhardh thanks I have corrected it now. Typo error

Comment: @koder . you said "Any dereferencing needed is done in printf" Great this answer my question. Great

Comment: @koder So by mentiond "%s" the  point variable "p" will be instructed to be dereference by the format specifier "%s". Is this a compiler implemetation or it is a language specification dictating that? I just wonder. thanks

Comment: @amedsvensson the `printf` interface is specified in the C standard. It is implemented in the C library as a normal function. Compilers can check that the parameters given do match the format string, but only if those warnings are enabled.

Comment: @koder Great thanks  I did not turn on the wrarning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're confused about some fundamental basics in C.

In case of

```
char *p;
```

- `p` is a pointer to a series of `char`, which is in fact a `\0` terminated
  string. This string can be printed with `printf("%s", p);`
- Since `p` is a pointer you can print the memory address it points to `printf("%p", p);`, which is exactly the same as if `p` was defined as `void *p;`
- `*p` dereferences the first `char` in the string pointed to by `p`, which is essentially the same as `p[0]`. This string can be printed with `printf("%c", *p);` or `printf("%c", p[0]);`